# SCRIPT1004: Expected ';' error in the browser

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I am using this script to hide 'Edit' button from SharePoint ribbon on my custom webpart's ascx page and calling it in the page load:

```
   function hideEdit() 
{

  var edit = document.getElementById("Ribbon.ListForm.Manage,EditItem-Large");

  edit.style.display = "none";
        alert ("I am an alert box!");

  }

   _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideEdit");
```

and I am getting two annoying errors:

> 1)SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'
>
> 2)SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null
>   reference

I have checked like 100 times, there is no semicolon missing. Any clue whats happening here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code

Comment: how about `edit` is `undefined`? maybe because `"Ribbon.ListForm.Manage,EditItem-Large"` does not look like a valid selector. Please try to learn some JS basics (like debugging). This would have made this mistake obvious.

Comment: so what shall i do in this case @Mx.

Comment: i just checked in chrome , it gives "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var" error

Comment: Your problem is really basic and hasnt anything to do with SharePoint. Try to get more knowledge about JS itself and you will find this errors dont appear anymore.

Comment: i will get the knowledge , but would u pls tell me what i have to do to resolve it , as u say it is very basic then just tell me what modifications r needed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35497/discussion-between-mx-and-mohammed-tauheed).

Comment: The reason Mx. is saying that `"Ribbon.ListForm.Manage,EditItem-Large"` does not look like a valid selector is because you have a comma (`,`) in between `Manage` and `EditItem-Large`, when it should be a period (`.`).  Try replacing that, and see what you get.  Not sure about the `Expected ';'` error.

Comment: @DylanCristy i changed the script , and still the same SCRIPT1004: Expected ';' error . :(

Comment: Right, as I said, it's hard to see from the code you posted where that error is coming from. But, changing the comma to a period got rid of the second error `Unable to get property 'style' of undefined `, correct?

Comment: yes it went away

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have entered the selector wrong. THere is never a comma in a selector. Instead of using Javascript, you can achieve this by CSS.
You can use the following css to hide the Edit button in the Ribbon.

```
#Ribbon\.ListItem\.Manage\.EditProperties-Large
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: on SharePoint always try to go CSS before JavaScript 
css style is applied right away, JavaScript will load and then apply you'll see the blinking (good answer +1)